# How to get name of JavaScript Class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

Let's take the following example code:

```
var ns = {}; // Some namespace

ns.Test = function()
{
    // Constructor of class Test
};

var inst = new ns.Test();
var className = hereIsTheMagic(inst); // Must return "ns.Test"
```

So I create a class named 'Test' in namespace 'ns' and an instance of this class named 'inst'. Now I want to find out the class name. How can I do this?

Up to now I solved this problem by giving each class a string property with the class name so I could use `inst.constructor.className` to access the class name. But if possible I would like to stop doing this because it is pretty error-prone when copy/pasting classes.

If there is no solution which works in all current browsers maybe there is at least some new feature in some future ECMAScript spec which provides access to class names?

Comment: don't sure this is possible, but my question is why you trying to do this? Mostly it will ruin off your OOP

Comment: @Frizi: I can't speak for kayahr, but it can be useful for error reporting.

Comment: @Frizi: I need this primarily for object serialization/deserialization. I just found out that Safari supports a special `displayName` property which is used to name anonymous functions in the profiler. So maybe it's a good idea to use this, too. So first check for `name` and if this is not there then check for `displayName` which I have to set manually for all classes.

Comment: I use AS3, and it has a typeof operator to return the class name, so I have a Json.stringify method now that can handle circular references and stores all the object type names so it can revive the entire object graph back to its original state, complete with strongly-typed instances.  It's compatible with JSON.NET too, so I can stringify something in Flash, send it to .NET and revive the instance on the server.  Class definitions are mirrored on the server in .NET and a custom type resolver handles special type name mapping (e.g. AS3 'Object' revived as .NET 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have classes, it has *constructor functions* and the prototype chain. Together, they can look a bit like classes, but they really aren't. :-)

No, there's no standard way that `hereIsTheMagic` can find the string "ns.Test" in your example, not even in ECMAScript 5. For one thing, `ns.Test` may not be the only property referring to that function (what if you added `ns.OtherTest = ns.Test;`, for instance).

JavaScript does have the concept of *functions* having proper names, but there's no standard way to access the proper name of a function, and even if you could, the function you're calling `ns.Test` is *anonymous*. The property you've assigned it to on `ns` has a name (`Test`), but the function does not.

You could give the function a name:

```
var ns = {}; // Some namespace
(function() {
    ns.Test = ns_Test;

    function ns_Test() {
    // Constructor of class Test
    }
})();
```

...which is a good idea, because it [helps tools help you](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html), but there's no standard way for JavaScript code itself to get at that name. (Don't do `ns.Test = function ns_Test() { ... };`, though. It should work, but there are various implementations of ECMAScript that have various bugs related to it. More about that in [the article linked above](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html).)

---

**Update**: I probably should have said: There are *non*-standard ways to get at the proper name of a function (`ns_Test` in my example above).

The easiest of these is the `name` property on function instances, which is supported by **many** implementations, including:

- Firefox's SpiderMonkey
- Chrome's V8
- Opera's engine (I don't know its name)
- Safari's engine (including Safari mobile)

...so `alert(ns_Test.name);` would alert "ns_Test". But it is *non*-standard and not supported by any version of JScript (Microsoft's engine), not even the version used by IE9 (now finally released!). Here's a quick tester page: http://jsbin.com/oxuva3

Note that, again that's the proper name of the function (see my example above), not the name of the property you've assigned it to.

If `name` isn't there, you can use `toString()` on the function object, which *may* (or may not) return a string representation of the function (e.g., "function ns_Test() { ... }"). That's completely non-standard, but common on desktop browsers; it doesn't work on several mobile browsers, and probably a bad idea in any case. :-)

Comment: Great explanation, T.J. :) I'll also throw in [this compatibility table](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/non-standard/) of mine, which lists some of the non-standard ES extensions (including function's name property)

Comment: Note that you can also add a name to a function expression: `ns.Test = function ns_Test() { ... };`. That name is also available via `ns.Test.name`.

Comment: @AxelRauschmayer: You can *in theory*, but as I said in the answer, it's fraught with difficulty in the wild: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/double-take.html | http://kangax.github.com/nfe/